# No space left, but actually there is!

Tags: debian, hard-disk

on my debian while i move or copy a file into one of my drives, it keeps saying there isn't any spaces left, but actually there is about 60 GB of free spaces.

The output of `du -d 1 -h` is the following.

```
16M ./one    
32G ./two     
48G ./three    
39G ./four    
18G ./five    
135G    .
```

`df -h` outputs this.

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6                  200G  136G   65G  68% /mnt/SU
```

The output of `df -i` is the following.

```
Filesystem                  Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda6                 68680588 1524136 67156452    3% /mnt/SU
```

and also `sudo lsof |grep -i deleted` outputs this.

[image]

The drive is partitioned for about 200 GB. All the other commands showing the disk size indicate there is space left.
When I remove some files, it keeps saying it again, even when copying a text file.

Is there any solution?

Comment: On a Linux FS, `rm` is not sufficient to guarantee that file space (and the inode) is actually returned to the FS. This only happens if/when all processes that have opened the files have closed them (so erasing a `live` log file is usually a bad idea).

Comment: What file system is the device? What block size? Any quota? Any file opened on it (see `lsof`)?

Comment: @xenoid it's NTFS, a usual drive, i'm storing some movie files and some executable files like firefox and vscode. running them every day.

Comment: So this makes things very different, since NTFS may not behave as your regular Linux FS... Add this is in blinking red in your initial question.

Comment: @xenoid so you suggest to change the drive's format or move executable files?

Comment: Not yet. But you may have more luck asking where there are more NTFS experts  ([SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/NTFS) for instance)

Comment: Is the file you're moving less than 65G?

Comment: @rush what do you mean the file i'm moving>

Comment: @Faramarz can you show `ls -l` for the file you're trying to copy? I'd like to learn whether its size is more than 60G.

Comment: @rush no its just a txt file, it's 1 KB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some deleted files might hold up the disk/filesystem space, run the below command as a root privileged account to check which deleted files are holding up the space

```
lsof < name_of_filesystem> | grep -i deleted
```

Once you know the files, then find out what services is related to that file and stop and start the service that will resolves and free up the disk space.

Hope this will helps, still if you sees please paste the error screenshot, thanks.

Comment: there is a huge output, shows this servies: ImageIO, Worker, Chrome, ImgDecode, Web, DataStora, Firefox and so on, i'll paste screenshot